# Paging Recordsets from SQL Serverside

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I've been banging my head off this one for a while. I want to call 1k records from a SQL database and page them per 100. In classic ASP (where I'm moving from) this was dead easy to do with ADODB but with VB using ADO.net I can't find a single way that doesn't involve stored procs (which I want to avoid for now). It seems really stupid to call all 1k and sort it programmatically.

Edit:
It's SQL Server 2005 / .net 4.0 / Visual Studio 2010.

Edit 2:
Just to reiterate, I have Googled extensively and don't want to use stored procedures. There are many ways to get paged data but everything I see involves paging the data in the program rather than from the server.

edit 3:
Here's an example of server side paging using Classic ASP, it doesn't need anything server side. (It's using Access but it's the same for SQL)
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/202125

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? If it's 2012 you can use the [OFFSET FETCH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) clause to do pagination.

Comment: Just https://www.google.com/search?q=ado.net+sql+server+paging you should find plenty of examples (e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18148/SQL-Server-Paging-Results) but you will probably have to use an SP for that

Comment: About your Edit 2: Yes stored procedure is a "program" but it runs on the server - hence paging is done *server-side* as you needed. There's no magic bullet that would do that for you - some server-side code is needed to provide data for requested page.

Answer (score 0):

ROW_NUMBER() is your answer here.  If your dataset has fields that support [deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) results, you can tie into said field(s) as follows:

Build Test Data Set:

```
DECLARE @RecordSet TABLE
(
    ID  INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    VALUE   VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @RecordSet (VALUE) VALUES ('One')
INSERT INTO @RecordSet (VALUE) VALUES ('Two')
INSERT INTO @RecordSet (VALUE) VALUES ('Three')
INSERT INTO @RecordSet (VALUE) VALUES ('Four')
INSERT INTO @RecordSet (VALUE) VALUES ('Five')
INSERT INTO @RecordSet (VALUE) VALUES ('Six')
INSERT INTO @RecordSet (VALUE) VALUES ('Seven')
INSERT INTO @RecordSet (VALUE) VALUES ('Eight')
INSERT INTO @RecordSet (VALUE) VALUES ('Nine')
INSERT INTO @RecordSet (VALUE) VALUES ('Ten')
```

Deterministic Runs based off either ID or VALUE fields:

```
-- Deterministic - Ordering Numerically by PKey
SELECT ID, VALUE, RowNum
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 0 ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM @RecordSet
    WHERE VALUE LIKE '%e%'
) t
WHERE  t.RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 6

-- Deterministic - Ordering Alphanumerically by Value
SELECT ID, VALUE, RowNum
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 0 ORDER BY VALUE) AS RowNum
    FROM @RecordSet
    WHERE VALUE LIKE '%e%'
) t
WHERE  t.RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 6
```

As you can see you can adjust the WHERE clause based off of RowNum field to "Window" your results.

If you run into a situation where the results cannot be generated deterministically (e.g. [nondeterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm)), but you still NEED to window things, you can use the following trick which I credit to this CONNECT article: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/383888/fully-support-position-in-xquery

```
-- Nondeterministic Ordering -- Probably want to avoid as these results are not guaranteed to be repeatable
SELECT ID, VALUE, RowNum
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 0 ORDER BY NULLIF(0*RAND(), 0)) AS RowNum
    FROM @RecordSet
    WHERE VALUE LIKE '%e%'
) t
WHERE  t.RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 6
```

Hope that helps,

John